# I am playing pokemon go but suddenly I can't catch any Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

Hello There I am playing  pokemon go But suddenly i can't Catch any pokemon

i am trying form 2 hrs

Even 10 cp pokemon run away

please help me

Comment: Have you been spoofing? If so it is probably a soft ban.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely cheated. All Pokémon running away is a kind of "soft ban" after cheating with your GPS location.

You will have to wait it out (the time varies) until you can catch Pokémon again. And of course turn off your fake GPS apps